# Are new questions regarding Windows XP on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic, on-topic

Does superuser follow the same policy as askubuntu to mark new questions about "no-longer supported" operating systems as off-topic?

Comment: There are many features such as networking that should "just work" across Windows versions and those have been generally allowed quite happily.  As long as people aren't asking how to use the latest whizz-bang graphics cards or software that publicly dropped XP support then the questions are fine for the time being.  Ubuntu is different in that being on the latest branch is, typically, a matter of a few clicks and a short wait while it gets going. Windows is paid for and people cling harder to old versions.

Comment: @Mokubai - what do you think of this question : http://superuser.com/questions/1114648/windows-xp-embedded-cloning-2-partitions-display ?

Comment: That question is borderline.  It could be that XPe is largely irrelevant and the problem is with his formatting/cloning tool or he is not setting the compact flash card up properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Are new questions regarding Windows XP on-topic?

Short answer: Yes they are on-topic.

We allow all sorts of questions about old (outdated) operating systems.

We may not be able to answer them though ... and you may get people suggesting you should upgrade ...

Comment: Well, we even have questions on pure DOS and Windows 3.1[1]

Comment: @CanadianLuke yep. What I said already.

Comment: David's probably covered the essentials on our end. Its worth noting that *community standards differ*. AU has an explicit close reason for this `This question is specific to an end of life Ubuntu release. These are no longer supported and are therefore off-topic here. To upgrade, see: How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?`. We do not.