# What to do with a question about a script for Windows XP that became a list of different types of scripts

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, flagging

[How do I set the desktop background on Windows from a script?](https://superuser.com/q/277805/152004) from 2008 has 8 answers,

- the OP usercard shows the OP user name but not a link to their profile.
- It hasn't an accepted answer.
- none of the answers fully address what was asked by the OP as all missed the part related to "some kind of scheduled task".
- Some answers are recommending software.
- Some answers are about command lines
- Some answers are asing files to handle command lines, one use a .bat file another use a .ps file.
- One answer is about using a vbs script.
- One answer is about using Python.

It's not clear that most of the answers nowadays works with Windows XP, the version of Windows mentioned by the OP and correspoing to the versioned tag used: [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp).

I don't know what is the stand of SU in regard old questions about outdated versions of Windows getting answers tested on newer versions instead of the version specified in the question.

I'm wondering if

- it should be closed as *seeking recommendations* and
- if there are better tags than the current assigned to the question:

  [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows)[windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)[script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/script)[desktop-customization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-customization)

---

Responses

| Response Summary | Score +/ 0 / - | Related Tags |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [1st](https://superuser.com/a/277808/152004) from 2008. Recommends a system util called bginfo. Includes a link to an artile that claims be published on September 2022. According to the linked page, the utility works for Windows 8.1 and higher and Windows Server 2012 and higher. | + | [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8)[windows-server-2012](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-server-2012) |
| [2nd](https://superuser.com/a/277810/152004) from 2008. Provide a command-line a brief instructions. | + | [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line) |
| [3rd](https://superuser.com/a/277813/152004) from 2011. Provides code to be saved as a batch file (.bat) and brief instructions. | + | [batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) |
| [4th](https://superuser.com/a/477896/152004) from 2012. Suggest to create Console App with a SharpDevelop. Provide very brief instructions and code. Mentions that was tested in a specific edition of Windows 7. | + | [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) |
| [5th](https://superuser.com/a/1254365/152004) from 2017, for Windows 7. Provides command lines. | 0 | [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line) |
| [6th](https://superuser.com/a/1442765/152004) from 2019, vbs script. Provides script and brief instructions. | + | [vbscript](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) |
| [7th](https://superuser.com/a/1519604/152004) from 2020, use PowerShell. Provides reference and code. | 0 | [powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powershell) |
| [8th](https://superuser.com/a/1624831/152004) from 2021, use Python. Provides reference and code. | + | [python](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/python) |

---

While I was searching about how similar questions were tagged, I found some that might be duplicates. The purpose of adding these questions here is just to help  regarding the tags

| Possible duplicates | Tags |
| --- | --- |
| [Schedule Windows XP wallpaper change without additional apps](https://superuser.com/q/57140/152004) | [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)[scheduled-tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tags) [desktop-customization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-customization) |
| [How to set custom JPG wallpaper using script for new user accounts (WinXP)](https://superuser.com/q/83888/152004) | [windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp) [desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop) [script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/script) |
| [Automatic change wallpaper at specific time](https://superuser.com/q/318650/152004) | [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) [desktop-customization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/desktop-customization) |

While non of these questions includes tags related to the Windows registry, the question in focus mentions that the OP used a script to modify a Windows registry key. Several answers having a script, what the script do is to modify the registry.

- [[windows-registry] wallpaper](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bwindows-registry%5D%20wallpaper) returns 41 results.
- [registry wallpaper](https://superuser.com/search?q=registry+wallpaper)
- [registry desktop background](https://superuser.com/search?q=registry+desktop+background)

Considering the above, I'm wondering if the  [windows-registry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-registry) should be added.

---

Related

- [Are batch script questions allowed on Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7736/152004)
- [Are new questions regarding Windows XP on-topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11731/152004)
- [Reviewing questions including "is there a script" about userscripts](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14908/152004)

Comment: "the OP usercard shows the OP user name but not a link to their profile" - IIRC its a deleted account from before deleted accounts were anonymoised.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I think that it might also helpful to include [tag:regedit] / [tag:windows-registry]

Comment: On the other hand - in hindsight, the registry wasn't the 'best' way to resolve the issue - and it would potentially invalidate most of the answers

Comment: Considering that the OP mentioned that he used a "cscript" and modified a registry key, is not extrange that the question attracted scripts to modify in one way or another the registry. I think that the seven answers that provided "scripts" didn't included fuller explanations that might be required when handling the registry. P.S. I don't know if 147k views in 14 years qualify the question as important, i.e. to add a bounty to ask for a canonical answer an in such case what could be an effective way to comunicate all the concerns. Do you think that might be worthy to offer a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

Do we really need to? Its different 'portable' approaches to a problem, and it isn't explicitly a gimme a codez question. Its also not a 'clear' software recommendation - but recommending software and the use of it is fine.

Even today, a question of that type *could* be asked in a way that's alright - it shows what OP has done and looked at, and their expected outcome.

It *was* clearly on topic when it was asked (and XP still isn't that retro is it?)

I'd say its fine to leave it as it is.

Comment: Windows XP is quickly becoming retro, I would argue, Windows 7 might get there first due to the Windows Updates that blocked processors beyond a certain product generation. Windows XP oddly didn't receive a similar block.  Of course very quickly, neither will run on modern processors, I expect the ability to boot to legacy operating systems to not be possible on newer processor within 3 years.

Comment: 'Sunsetting' on topicality is... an interesting thing. We've never done it, and a lot of things *haven't* changed between even 95 and 98. It'll probably need a meta post but I personally don't see the value in it

Comment: When I talk about legacy, talking about 32-bit, Intel and AMD are itching to kill support for 32-but operating systems. Takes a ton of silicon to support something that neither Linux, Apple, nor Windows is supporting in supported versions of their respective Operating Systems.

Comment: I have seen in several places in Meta Super User (MSU) that questions that might look as a recommendation or that might be answering by providing a recommendation should not end in a broad list of things. I thought that this was  some sort of SU *concensus* among the assidous MSU users.... anyway, lets put the "close as recommendation" part aside for a while, what about the tags? Should add tags based on the answers having a positive score? 6 of 8 answers have a positve score. I will add the tags and +/- of each answer in a moment.

Comment: It should not *elicit*  a list, but there's often more than one approach to a problem. That it *ends up* being a list of 'full' answers on its own isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [The scope of the [windows] tag](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12291/152004)

> Bear in mind that the tag is associated with the question rather than the answers. The answers should be responsive to the question but beyond that, answers can address other versions.

Conclusion regarding Windows tags, keep [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows)[windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp), do not add tags for other Windows versions.

Suggested to add [windows-registry](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-registry)

I'm still wondering if [command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line) or [batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) might be better than [script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/script).

**Related**

- [tag + tag-version, or just tag-version?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1261/152004)
- [The scope of the [windows] tag](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12291/152004)